# Chef cron provider creates multiple crontab entries

Tags: chef-infra, cron

We are running Chef 11.4.4 with a non-omnibus install (it is installed as a gem).  In one of our cookbooks we use the cron provider like:

```
checksum   = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(node['fqdn'] || 'unknown-hostname')
sleep_time = checksum.to_s.hex % node['custom_command']['splay'].to_i

cron "custom_command" do
  user "custom_user"
  hour 0
  minute 0
  command "/bin/sleep #{sleep_time}; /home/custom_user/custom_command.sh"
end
```

Somehow this appears to create multiple cron entries about 0.01% of the time.  On an affected server we get the following output from `crontab -u custom_user -l`:

```
# Chef Name: custom_command
0 0 * * * /bin/sleep 7035; /home/custom_user/custom_command.sh
# Chef Name: custom_command
0 0 * * * /bin/sleep 7035; /home/custom_user/custom_command.sh
```

Running chef-client does not modify the crontab.  But editing the crontab and removing both entries then running chef-client again will fix the issue.  Then the `crontab -u custom_user -l` output looks (correctly) like:

```
# Chef Name: custom_command
0 0 * * * /bin/sleep 7035; /home/custom_user/custom_command.sh
```

This issue appear to pop up at random - we currently have to fix about 1 server a day.  So it seems like a race issue of some kind.

Has anyone else experienced this same issue?  I have not seen it using the `cron_d` provider.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is likely a bug in the Chef `cron` provider and should be reported at https://tickets.opscode.com.

Comment: Thanks @sethvargo - submitted as [CHEF-5256](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5256)

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like a bug but a possible workaround might be to delete all crontab jobs just before creating them:
`crontab -r -u USERNAME`